# Moq system under tests void method

Tags: c#, testing, moq

This is my code

```cs
public class IUserService
{
    void Register(string email, string password);
}

public class UserService
{
    private readonly IUserRepository userRepository;
    
    public UserService(IUserRepository userRepository)
    {
        this.userRepository = userRepository;
    }

    public void Register(string email, string password)
    {
        ...
        var registered = senderIdRepository.Insert(email, password).Result;
        SendRegistrationConfirmationEmail(email);
        
        return registered;
    }
    
    public void SendRegistrationConfirmationEmail(string email)
    {
        ...
    }
}

public class UserServiceTest
{
    private readonly ISenderIdService sut;
    private readonly Mock<IUserRepository> userRepository = new Mock<IUserRepository>();
    
    [Fact]
    public void User_register_test()
    {
        // arrange
        userRepository.Setup(x => x.Insert(It.IsAny<string>(), It.IsAny<string>()))
            .Returns(Task.FromResult(true));
        
        var email = "testEmail@gmail.com";
        var password = "testPass@#$d";
            
        // act
        var result = sut.Register(email, password);
        
        // assert
        Assert.Equal(1, result);
    }
}
```

When I run test `User_register_test()`, `SendRegistrationConfirmationEmail()` is launched. I want to prevent that, because I don't want test email sending. Is it possible to do it without having `SendRegistrationConfirmationEmail` in `IUserService`?

What I would like to do is ignore whole `SendRegistrationConfirmationEmail()` when launching `User_register_test()`, but I dont want to have `void SendRegistrationConfirmationEmail(string email)` in `IUserService` interface to have it mocked. It it possible to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cleanest way to solve this is to move the mail-related methods to a separate interface and a dedicated class. On the one hand, you could mock it easily; on the other hand, it also supports the Single-Responsibility-Principle.

If you do not want to do this, there is also a hack that you can use. It will work, but it has its downsides:

- Make `SendRegistrationConfirmationEmail` virtual (and maybe protected).
- In the test project, you create a derived class that overrides `SendRegistrationConfirmationEmail` and replaces the send-mail-functions.
- Instead of testing `UserService` directly, you test the derived class that differs only in the implementation of `SendRegistrationConfirmationEmail`.

As you see, you also have to do some work to create the hack (maybe more than solving it in a clean way); also the probability that this hack grows and that it is used later in ways that were not intended is high. Therefore, I'd opt for the clean way and refactor `SendRegistrationConfirmationEmail` into an interface of its own.

Comment: Thanks, it works. If I understand correctly, if mail-related methods be in `IUserService` interface, that wouldn't change anything, right? Still, this hack would be necessary?

Comment: It will only help, if you inject an instance of `IUserService` into `UserService` and call the mail-methods on the injected instance. Then you can inject a mocked version during testing. This would be a rather strange construct. Therefore, I'd recommend to either create a clearly mail-related interface and inject an instance of this into `UserService` (or use the hack if you want to)

Comment: I'm not sure how would it look like. Can you give me an example?

Comment: I've created a sample for IUserService with mail-function, see https://dotnetfiddle.net/wy6UGQ; I'll create one with a normal injection (the preferred way imho)

Comment: This is the sample for the preferred implementation: https://dotnetfiddle.net/hHL8IB Have fun :-)